# How to convert ordered collections to data frame with the proper key value pairs in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have to get the content from a page that is in XML format into a data frame.

My code to read the file is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict
from collections import OrderedDict

x= urlopen('https://mpr.datamart.ams.usda.gov/ws/report/v1/cattle/LM_CT138?filter=%7B%22filters%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22Report%20date%22,%22operatorType%22:%22EQUAL%22,%22values%22:%5B%224/1/2022%22%5D%7D%5D%7D').read().decode('utf-8')

data = xmltodict.parse(x)

print(data)
```

The output is in ordered Dictionary and I tried number of ways to convert it to the required data frame.

Example

```
keys = data.keys()
values = data.values()

print ("keys : ", str(keys))
print ("values : ", str(values))

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values)
```

I am getting the entire dictionary in one column. I want them split with according to the key values in different coulms.

Comment: You are getting it in one column because the dictionary is nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored in a nested dict as you see on the screenshot[image: original data screenshot]
You are trying to create a dataframe with column names being *"first level keys"*. Obviously, you are obtaining *"first level values"* in the **"results"** column and the whole dict inside the **"report"** cell.
You need to call the correct level of the nested dictionary to get the correct dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import xmltodict

url = 'https://mpr.datamart.ams.usda.gov/ws/report/v1/cattle/LM_CT138?filter=%7B"filters":%5B%7B"fieldName":"Report%20date","operatorType":"EQUAL","values":%5B"4/1/2022"%5D%7D%5D%7D'
r = requests.get(url)
data = xmltodict.parse(r.text)
data_ = data['results']['report']['record']['report']['record']  # returns the list of "OrderedDict"-s with keys = column names
pd.DataFrame(data_)
```

Sorry for using **requests**, I'm not really familiar with a **urllib** library

Comment: I used this and it works well but when I am trying to loop in with dates and different report IDs, I am getting errors.

Comment: @Shruthi Ravishankar , without looking at your code or data you are processing I can only guess that the structure of reports for different dates/IDs is different. Try to process a couple of these reports individually by iteratively accessing different levels of the dict manually

Comment: Thank you. Here is the question with the proper code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71750414/how-to-rotate-user-agents-as-to-not-get-blocked

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get('https://mpr.datamart.ams.usda.gov/ws/report/v1/cattle/LM_CT138?filter=%7B%22filters%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22Report%20date%22,%22operatorType%22:%22EQUAL%22,%22values%22:%5B%224/1/2022%22%5D%7D%5D%7D')

root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
records = [record.attrib for record in root.iterfind("report/record/report/record")]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Every column comes out as string. You may convert it to other data types as needed.